# i want to insert data to DB but undefined index error show

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-6

i want to recover the input to insert it in My DB but an undefined index error show but i m sure that the index are simillar!!!!!
this my ProjectDetail.vue form:

```
    <form type="post"  @submit.prevent="ajouterCommentaireReponse(comment.id)"  v- 
        bind:id="comment.id " class="d-none">

   <div class="input-group input-group-sm mt-2 ml-2">
    <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="replycomment"  
    type="text"  placeholder="commenter.." style="width:450px;" >

     <div class="input-group-append">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Commenter</button>
      </div>
    </div>
   </form>
```

and this the controller function:

```
   public function storereply(Request $request,$key){
    $data =$request->all();
   $commentaire=Commentaire::find($key);
    $commentairereply =new Commentaire;
    $commentairereply->user_id= auth()->user()->id;
    $commentairereply->body = $data['replycomment'];
   $commentairereply->comment_user_name=$commentaire->user->name;
   $commentaire->comments()->save($commentairereply);


     }
```

Comment: have you tried to `dd($data);` to see if replycomment actually exist as one of the key? also try `dd($request->replycomment)` while you're at it..

Comment: i have try dd($data) but nothing happen!!!

Comment: he don't show me anything

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm a bit confused with the code. But I think you want to save to `$commentaire`, and to do so, the last line of `storereply` function should look like this

```
public function storereply(Request $request,$key){
    $data =$request->all();
    $commentaire=Commentaire::find($key);
    $commentairereply =new Commentaire;
    $commentairereply->user_id= auth()->user()->id;
    $commentairereply->body = $data['replycomment'];
    $commentairereply->comment_user_name=$commentaire->user->name;
    // $commentaire->comments()->save($commentairereply);
    $commentairereply->save();
}
```

Comment: no the issue in replycomment  index he show me an error of Undefined index
but the name of input and and the  $data['replycomment']; are similar

Comment: have you checked the `$fillable` in model ?
usually I have the undefined index either because of fillable or index is actually not exist